# What's the van 't Hoff factor of dilute aqueous ferrous sulphate solution?

Tags: aqueous-solution, solutions

Is it more than one or less than one?

Here is what I think: since it is a dilute and aqueous solution, so $\ce{FeSO4}$ will be hydrated and new formula will be $\ce{FeSO4*7H2O}$.

Thus, the abnormal mass would be greater than the normal molar mass.

Therefore, van 't Hoff factor would be less than $1$. Is that correct?

Comment: [Policy on AMIRITE questions](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/3396/34388)

Comment: Since it is dilute, the ions will dissociate: $\ce{FeSO4 -> Fe^2+ + SO4^2-}$, and whence hydration?

Comment: @DHMO Firstly, it's not policy yet; secondly, even though it's tempting, please don't make obnoxious edits like that. All of us are very frequently tempted to leave snarky comments. Whether you rise above that to be a better person is up to you.